# New-AzureBatchPool -VirtualMachineSize possible values

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, azure-batch

I'm starting to dig into Azure Batch.

I am trying to create a Pool from PowerShell and I've noticed that on the Microsoft [documentation page of the command *New-AzureBatchPool*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.batch/new-azurebatchpool?view=azurermps-6.8.1) they tell us that in parameter "-VirtualMachineSize" we have to specify the size of the virtual machine.

Ok, but if I send "Standard_A1" as -VirtualMachineSize parameter, the request fails, but if I send "Small" (as I saw in the examples of the command) it works!

Is there is a documentation page that contains a table that relates the kind of values expected by this command ("Small") with the normal values ("Standard_A0", "Standard_L16s_v2" , etc.)?

Comment: There, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know where is stablished the relationship between "Small" and "Standard_A0" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are working with a previous generation. According to *[Previous generations of virtual machine sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-previous-gen)*:

*Standard A0 - A4 using CLI and PowerShell
In the classic deployment model, some VM size names are slightly different in CLI and PowerShell:*

```
Standard_A0 is ExtraSmall
Standard_A1 is Small
Standard_A2 is Medium
Standard_A3 is Large
Standard_A4 is ExtraLarge
```

Comment: That was it! thanks a lot, It seems that for these types of VMs Powershell uses the classic deployment model names, but for the other VMs Powershell accepts the new ones.

Comment: And that's because "New-AzureBatchPool" command uses classic deployment model.

Comment: All except the first paragraph is copied from the indicated source. It is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) if copied text is not ***clearly*** marked as such. In most cases, that would be by quoting (e.g., block quoting). Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*